# Metric Spaces given set of non-decreasing functions

Tags: metric-spaces

I have a Metric Spaces exam on Tuesday and the following question comes up a lot. I have attempted it multiple times but i cant seem to come up with a valid solution. I could really do with a solution as soon as possible. Thanks in advance.

consider the metric space $(X,d)$ where $X$ is the set of functions $f:[0,1]\to[0,1]$, and the distance $d$ is given by

$$d(f,g)=\Vert f−g\Vert_{\infty}=\sup\{|f(t)−g(t)|:t\in[0,1]\}$$
let

$J=\{f\in X|\forall x,y\in [0,1],x\le y:f(x)\le f(y)\}$
be the set of non-decreasing functions in $X$

(a) is $J$ closed in $(X,d)$ (12 marks)

(b)is $J$ open in $(X,d)$ (12 marks)

(c) is $J$ compact (12 marks)

Comment: Please write out explicitly your attempts in the question. What did you do when attempting to solve this problem?

Comment: Also, for future reference, when asking question, you should format the math in mathJax as described [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: Apologies, I am new to this website.

Comment: @ClementYung  My understanding of the topic is quite poor and despite research I was unable to find anything useful relating to this question. My attempts are non-sensical. I attempted to show that if J was closed then a a sequence in J would be cauchy and then the sequence would also be cauchy in X.

Comment: $J$ is closed if it contains all its limit points, i.e. if for all sequences of function $\{f_i\}_{i\in \Bbb N} \subseteq X$ which converges to some function $f$, we have that $f \in J$. $J$ is compact if it is closed and bounded.

Comment: @Norse: There is a bit of disorderliness in the applying of universal quantifiers in the above characterization of closedness: one says that a subset $M \subseteq X$ is closed in the (unmentioned) topology of space $X$ if it contains all its **adherent points** (it is true that this is equivalent to requiring that it contains all its **accumulation points**, however what you describe in your comment above seems to be a general adherent point, so let us be precise).

Comment: @Norse: Next, in a first countable space, a point $x \in X$ will be adherent to subset $M$ if and only if there exists a sequence $t \in M^{\mathbb{N}}$ of points in $M$ converging to $x$.  Therefore, the correct quantification in your above description would be: ''$M$ is a closed subset if it contains any point $x \in X$ which occurs as a limit of some sequence $t$ of points in $M$''.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\{f_n\}_{n \in \Bbb N}\subseteq J$ be a convergent sequence of functions in $J$. Let $f$ denote the limit of the sequence, i.e. $f(x) = \lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(x)$.

We prove that $f\in J$ proving that $J$ is closed: Let $x, y \in [0,1]$ such that $x \le y$, then
$$
f(x)=\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(x) \le \lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(y)=f(y)
$$
since $f_n\in J$ for all $n$. Hence $f$ is non-decreasing, so $f \in J$, so $J$ contains all its limit points.

Comment: Thanks so much Norse.

Comment: @Gavink: as to the remaining two questions, since your given metric space is arc-connected (given $f, g \in X$ the map $[0,1] \to X, \lambda \mapsto \lambda f+(1-\lambda)g$ is continous) hence connected, so its only closed-open sets are the extreme ones (the full space itself and the empty subset); therefore, as $J$ is closed non-empty and proper, it cannot be also open. For c), $(X, d)$ is compact and therefore any closed subset is also compact.

Comment: @ΑΘΩ Thank you so much. I really appreciate the help.

Comment: @GavinK14: I actually made a big and ugly blunder in hastily replying without properly checking my background reasoning. What I said about b) is valid indeed, however what I said about c) is wrong: the topology given on $X$ is that of uniform convergence, and in order to discern the compactness of subset $M$ (I dislike the choice of $J$ for that set) one resorts to the Arzela-Ascoli theorem. However, $M$ will not be equicontinuous in points $x \in [0 ,\frac{1}{2})$, since for $\epsilon=\frac{1}{3}$ and for any $\delta>0$ there will exist increasing functions

Comment: @GavinK14 (continuation of the above): increasing functions such as the one (call it $f$) acting identically on $[0, x]$, affine and strictly increasing in mapping $[x, x+\frac{\delta}{2}]$ to $[x, 1]$ and then constantly equal to $1$ on $[x+\frac{\delta}{2}, 1]$. It will then be the case that $\left|f(x+\frac{\delta}{2})-f(x)\right|=1-x>\frac{1}{2}>\epsilon$, prohibiting equicontinuity.